# background image is cutting off text in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

My background image is cutting off my text when the screen size is adjusted smaller. The background image is also not 100% of the screen height when viewed in large screens. What am I doing wrong?

```
    .slider {
    background: url("../images/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    max-height: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: link to website is: www.irontimberco.com

Comment: Isn't that what overflow does?

Comment: as @zerro298 mentioned the overflow is cutting off the text. If the `.slider` needs to be bigger than 1200px high (as you have set a max-height) the text will be cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `min-height:100%` for `.slider` class and add `height: 100%` for their parent `body` tag.
Remove `width, overflow, height` in `.slider` class.

Should be -

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.slider {
  background: url("../images/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;

  min-height: 100%;
}
```